# Экранирование символа [ в символьном классе регулярного выражения

Tags: регулярные-выражения, qt, c++

```
QRegExp regexpsplineedit("[a-zA-Z\\[]{13}");
```

превращение мета символа `[` в обычный работает и с одним обратным слешем, но если делать с одним, то Qt creator выдает предупреждение `warning: C4129: '[' : unrecognized character escape sequence` .Почему так и какая разница между одним обратным слешем и двумя? А теперь проверил, что работает даже без слеша, то есть так `"[a-zA-Z[]{13}"`, а это почему происходит?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давайте обсудим регулярные выражения и escape-последовательности - отделим, так сказать, мух от котлет.

Известно, что в С принята нотация строковых констан с POSIX формой: escape-последовательностями "слэш с чем-то - это один спец. символ"

- \n - перевод строки
- \r - перевод каретки
- \0 - терминирующий символ
- \t, \b, \v, \a...

Соответственно, чтобы написать просто слэш ('\'), надо писать "\\", т.к. в одиночку он действовует на следующий символ, действуя на себя - даёт себя. Их конечное число, я, по-моему, даже все перечислил, это далеко не все символы ASCII.

Действительно [ - unrecognized character escape sequence - такого спец. символа нет.

Теперь регулярные выражения.

Если говорить строго математически - это некий алфавит (множество) и операции: объединения (U), конкатенации (х) и итерации (*).

Определение даётся индукционное:

1. Символ алфавита - регулярен.
2. Два (или одно для итерации) регулярных выражения, объединённые одной из трёх операций - регулярны.

Теперь обсудим синтаксис рег. выр. PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) - которые на самом деле нерегулярны, а много сильнее, благодаря "обратным ссылкам" и прочему.

- . - это любой символ алфавита (пусть алфавит - ASCII);
- цифры, взятые в { } - количество повторов, это операция конкатенации и операция объединения подряд нескольлько раз, но для краткости записаны как {n,m};
- символы, взятые в [ ] - это "любой из них", просто символы алфавита, их не надо экранировать слэшами ([.] - точка);
- но [^.] - это "все, кроме '.' "
- [a-z] - от а до z, т.к. в кодировках символы кодируются подряд идущими численными кодами, это сокращение тоже на самом деле мало-регулярно.

НО! Т.к. мы находимся к тому же в пространстве *POSIX и записываем выражения в строках, то на этот синтаксис накладываются наши escape-последовательности*.

- \. - это символ '.', \[ - это символ '[', но не escape-последовательности, комиплятор же не знает, что мы внутри обработчика регулярных последоватальностей, который всё понимает по-своему;
- [\\] - а это символ '\', [\^], [\-], "[\n]" или "\n"... Ну Вы меня понимаете?

В общем, это всё от-того... от лукавого.

Answer (score 3):

> Превращение мета символа [ в обычный работает и с одним обратным слешем,
>  но если делать с одним, то Qt creator выдает предупреждение warning: C4129: '[' : unrecognized character escape sequence. Почему так и какая разница между одним обратным слешем и двумя?

Обратный слэш `\` является специальным символом как внутри строковой константы в С, так и в языке регулярных выражений (PCRE). Если используются два слэша, то C компилятор съедает один слэш и pcre движок видит только оставшийся слэш и интерпретирует `\[` как просто `[`.

Если используется только один слэш, то C компилятор пытается проинтерпретировать `\[` последовательность. Такой последовательности нет, поэтому С компилятор отбрасывает слэш (не знаю, является ли это гарантированным поведением по С стандарту) и pcre движок видит только один символ `[`.

> А теперь проверил, что работает даже без слеша, то есть так "[a-zA-Z[]{13}", а это почему происходит?

Дополнительно, текст внутри `[]` также имеет свои правила, а именно `[` **не** является специальным символом внутри `[]`, поэтому его **не** нужно экранировать. Например, `"[[]"` -- корректное регулярное выражение.

---

Чтобы не производить двойную (или даже тройную в этом случае) интерпретацию строки в c++11 введены [raw string literals](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.ru/2012/05/c-11-faq.html#raw-strings):

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
  const char* s = R"foo(Hello\\
World
)")foo";
  assert(std::strcmp(s, "Hello\\\\\nWorld\n)\"") == 0);
}
```

Подобные `R"()"` константы удобно использовать, чтобы записывать регулярные выражения и файловые пути в Windows.