# Зачем в регулярных выражениях C++ regex дважды ставить бекслэш перед метасимволом b когда хочу указать конец или начало слова?

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения, экранирование

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
int main ()
{
    std::string str = "SERVER_COMPUTER";
    std::regex rx("\\bCOMPUTER\\b"); //6
    std::cout << std::regex_search(str, rx) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Зачем в этом примере дважды ставят бекслэши **\\b**? почему не работает только с одним? (строка 6)

Comment: Потому что бэкслеш является экранирующим символом.

Comment: То есть, грубо говоря, мы ставим 2 бэкслэша, чтобы в поток отправилось \bCOMPUTER\b а не 'backspace'COMPUTER'backspace' ?

Comment: Да, именно так.

Comment: связанный вопрос [Экранирование символа \[ в символьном классе регулярного выражения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/384583/23044)

Comment: Вопрос не имеет никакого отношения к регулярным выражениям. В обычных строковых и символьных литералах языков С и С++ следует ставить два бекслэша, чтобы получить один бекслэш в результате. Не важно, в каком контексте эти литералы используются - в регулярных выражениях или еще где.

Comment: @AnT если regex движок увидев, \b интерпретирует последовательность специальным образом, то имеет значение что regex или не regex — экранирование на нескольких уровнях происходит(превращение literal  в строку это только один из шагов): в зависимости от желаемого эффекта: граница слова или буквальное совпадение, придётся по разному экранировать. Дополнительно, внутри `[]` в regex могут свои правила быть. См. ссылку выше.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если не хочется запутывать регулярки еще и экранирующими символами, то можно использовать Raw литералы, в которых нет экранирующих символов.

```
std::regex rx(R"(\bCOMPUTER\b)");
```

Comment: У вас скобочек не хватает. Должно быть `R"(блабла)"`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, зачем?

Comment: @Qwertiy Ну, у raw строк такой синтаксис.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, а поподробнее можно?

Comment: @Qwertiy У raw строк можно задавать открывающий и закрывающий префикс / cуффикс. Это позволяет использовать внутри них даже двойные кавычки без окончания строки. `R"abc(Hello, "Word"!)abc"` -> `Hello, "Word"!`

Comment: @VTT Кавычки можно и без разделителя. Вот `)"` без разделителя уже нельзя, да.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Суть в том, что можно выбрать префикс так, что он не встретился в строке.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, VTT, спасибо, буду знать.

Comment: @VTT Точнее, в строке не должно встречаться `)разделитель"`. Так что для `R"(")"` разделитель не нужен.

Comment: @VTT Под разделителем я имею то, что вы назвали префиксом, конечно. :/